# How Webpack4 bundles ES6 code without importing babel-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

I was able to load sayHello.js:

```
export const sayHello = (name) => `Hello, ${name}`;
```

from index.js

```
import { sayHello } from './sayHello';
console.log(sayHello('John'));
```

webpack is able to generate dist/main.js without me having to use babel-loader.

How is it able to transpile and bundle es6 syntax without babel-loader?

Comment: As I know, since Webpack 2, Webpack understands ES6 imports.